# jsonpath expression for extracting element with maximum date

Tags: jsonpath

consider the following JSON:

```
{
  "entry": [
    {
      "content": "blah",
      "date": "2018-09-15T15:30:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "content": "trah",
      "date": "2018-09-16T15:30:00.000Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

then following expression can be used to extract last content:

```
$.entry[?(@.date=="2018-09-16T15:30:00.000Z")].content
```

however, I need to get the most up-to-date content hence I would expected to be able to write:

```
$.entry[?(max(@.date)].content
```

Any suggestions?
Perhaps writing a custom predicate function?

TIA,
Adrian.

Answer (score 0):

No expert I but perhaps changing:
`[?(max(@.date)]`
with
`[?(@.date.max()]`
will do the trick.